# Selenium 2.0 Found Element But Unable To Click

Tags: selenium, click, webdriver

I am using Selenium 2.0 for C# to find a radio button and click it. The code is as below:

```
IWebElement t = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='ctl00_Main__objObjectivesFeedback_ctl39']/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[@type='radio']"));
t.Click();
```

If I do a `Console.Write(t.GetAttribute("name"))`, it returns the correct element name, however, click does not work.

Btw, I am using FireFox 3.6.20.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
t.SendKeys(Keys.Space);
```

If it works the only downside is `SendKeys` does not wait for the page to finish loading if the event caused the page to reload. Usually not a problem for radio buttons but it's something to keep in mind.